# Jquery UI resizable binding onto outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to find a way to bind `.resizable` from an outer div, so that my newly appended inner divs will be resizable.

With standard jquery stuff like .click, i'd use an

```
$('.outer_div').on('click', '.inner_div_class', function(){..do_something..}).
```

But I'm kind of lost as to how to do this with jquery ui stuff.

Currently I'm calling `.resizable()` on the newly appended inner div right after a successful ajax call.  I'm pretty sure there must be a way to get .resizable to be called from an outer div.  Is there an alternate way to accomplish this?

(I'm particularly unhappy with my current solution because I'm implementing infinite scroll. and appending a lot of inner divs)

Comment: Nope. You have to bind the event directly to the element.

Comment: that is a darn shame. but thank you for the response =]